# $\int_d^{d+T} cos(nwt)dt = 0$ for $n ≠ 0$

Tags: integration

$\int_d^{d+T} cos(nwt)dt = 0$ for $n ≠ 0$

where $w$ is the circular frequency.

I tried proving this using an arbitrary value of n, ie n = 1. But I get:

$\frac{1}{w}[sin(\frac{\pi d}{T})(cos(1)-1)+ sin(1)cos(\frac{\pi d}{T})]$

Which does not look promising.

Anyone know how to do this? Any help is greatly appreciated!
Kind Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute $\text{u}=\text{n}\omega t$ and $\text{d}\text{u}=\text{n}\omega\space\text{d}t$:

$$\mathcal{I}\left(\text{d},\text{n},\text{T},\omega\right)=\int_\text{d}^{\text{d}+\text{T}}\cos\left(\text{n}\omega t\right)\space\text{d}t=\frac{1}{\text{n}\omega}\int_{\text{n}\omega\text{d}}^{\text{n}\omega\left(\text{d}+\text{T}\right)}\cos\left(\text{u}\right)\space\text{d}\text{u}=$$
$$\frac{1}{\text{n}\omega}\left[\sin\left(\text{u}\right)\right]_{\text{n}\omega\text{d}}^{\text{n}\omega\left(\text{d}+\text{T}\right)}=\frac{\sin\left(\text{n}\omega\left(\text{d}+\text{T}\right)\right)-\sin\left(\text{n}\omega\text{d}\right)}{\text{n}\omega}$$

So, when you want to solve:

$$\mathcal{I}\left(\text{d},\text{n},\text{T},\omega\right)=0$$

We get:

$$\sin\left(\text{n}\omega\left(\text{d}+\text{T}\right)\right)-\sin\left(\text{n}\omega\text{d}\right)=0$$

Comment: Couldn't you do it without the substitution? It's an elementary integral...

Answer (score 0):

Integrate the cosine, it's elementary.

$$\int_d^{d+T} \cos(n\omega t)\ \text{d}t = \frac{1}{n\omega}\left\{\sin(n\omega (d+T)) - \sin(n\omega d)\right\}$$

Then you want this equal to zero:

$$\frac{1}{n\omega}\left\{\sin(n\omega (d+T)) - \sin(n\omega d)\right\} = 0$$

That is ($n, \omega \neq 0$)

$$\sin(n\omega (d+T)) - \sin(n\omega d) = 0$$

$$\sin(n\omega (d+T)) = \sin(n\omega d)$$

Besides the trivial condition $T = 0$ you can make use of the periodicity of the sine function...